# How to push changes to old repo to GITHUB after downloading it

Tags: github, github-pages

I lost my PC data after hard-drive corruption. After that from my github repo i downloaded my code and made some changes and did `npm install`, but when i tried to push my changes to repo, it is saying there are no currently active repo to push. 
How to push my new changes to my old repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have cloned the repo on your local machine, that way you would have the git initialized. But, for now, you can follow the below steps.

```
git init
git remote add origin <github repo url>
```

The first line would initialize the git repo and the second would point it to the online repo you already have.

Comment: Oh thanks man ! Now i understood difference between Clone vs download in github. Now its resolved and i am able to commit changes to old repo

Answer (score 1):

You could have downloaded the repo with:

```
git clone <repo url>
```

but to answer your question:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git remote add origin <repo url>
```

you can then verify the remote url with:

```
git remote -v
```

after that check If your .gitignore file is there, if not create one and add node_modules/

after that just push it with:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

just check whether you have set the remote origin correctly.

```
$ git remote show origin
$ git remote -v
```

use the above commands to check your remote URL. if it is not set correctly, set the URL again.

```
$ git remote set-url < your repo URL here >
```

hope this will work